# How to show all legends in google Visualization: Pie Chart

Tags: visualization, legend, pie-chart

i am using Google visualization pie chart for showing my vote details.But the chart didn't showing the zero values and legends.
How to show all legends in Google Visualization: Pie Chart

Answer (score 14):

You can simply set the `sliceVisibilityThreshold` option to `0`. This will force all the legends to show.

```
var options = {
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
};
var data = /* ... */;

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(/* ... */);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to add a small value (0.005) to each of the values. When setting the sliceVisibilityThreshold: 1/25000, (1/25000 = 0.004) the slice/legend will be shown but the value will still be 0% due to rounding.

Comment: What I should mention is that my values are between 0 and 100 percent, so 1/25000 * 100 = .004